# Objective C syntax, making NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c

How can I do it shorter?

```
_adv[@"car"] = @{"lala" : @1};

NSMutableDictionary *car = [_adv[@"car"] mutableCopy];
car[@"haveCar"] = @NO;
_adv[@"car"] = car;
```

Comment: What about one line: `_adv[@"car"] = @{ @"haveCar" : @NO };`? You don't mention if there might be preexisting values or if the dictionary really needs to be mutable.

Comment: yes, I have preexisting values,

Comment: The 1st line in your posted code (before updating) made it appear otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ensure that a mutable dictionary is in use from start, then you can do:

```
_adv[@"car"][@"haveCar"] = @NO;
```

To ensure the mutable constraint, change the 1st line in your question from:

```
_adv[@"car"] = @{"lala" : @1};
```

to:

```
_adv[@"car"] = [@{"lala" : @1} mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableDictionary* car = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
car[@"lala"] = @1;
car[@"haveCar"] = @NO;
_adv[@"car"] = car;
```